# Eclipse - Maven Update Jar with dependencies struggling to be updated

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I work on two projects with a friend on Eclipse. One of them (Project 2) create a Maven Jar with dependencies which is used on the other project(Project 1).

Every time I change one of the objects created on my Project 2, Eclipse doesn't realize there is an update that can be used by project 1.

I clean, refresh, update project but 99% of the time, my Tomcat cannot be launched. It took me most of the times between a few hours and 48 hours to fix the problem without never knowing what went wrong.

How could I fix this?

Comment: You need to tell Eclipse to refresh Maven dependencies. Right click on the project, select Maven, select update dependencies, tick the force refresh checkbox too. Something like that, I don't have an Eclipse in front of me right now

Comment: So you have these both projects in same workspace in your Eclipse?

Comment: Yes they are in the same workspace.

Comment: I've already tried Maven Update dependencies with no success.